# How not to lose accents on vowels during exportation Oracle script

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, non-ascii-characters

I'm exporting a database in Oracle by running a script in SQLDeveloper

This is a part of the full script:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK
Insert into WSLC_CAT_MOD (ID_OPER,DSC_MOD,FCH_MOD) values (14,'Contingencia - Importaci'|| CHR(243) ||'n de Archivos',to_date('15/01/15','DD/MM/RR'));
```

I expect something like this when I consult in WSLC_CAT_MOD table:

```
14 | Contingencia - Importación de Archivos | 15/01/15
```

However I get this:

```
14 | Contingencia - Importacin de Archivos | 15/01/15
```

I can't get any of the characters with accent (á,é,í,ó,ú)

Comment: What is your database character set?  What is your client `nls_lang`?

Comment: How is it an export if you're hand-crafting the values? Are you generating the insert statements, including the embedded accented characters, programatically? And is there a reason you aren't using SQL Developer's built-in database export tool (or, indeed, data pump export)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`unistr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions224.htm) instead of [`chr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions026.htm); passing the hex equivalent of the decimal value you're currently using - e.g. for 243 that is [00f3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f3/index.htm):

```
insert into WSLC_CAT_MOD (ID_OPER,DSC_MOD,FCH_MOD)
values (14,
  'Contingencia - Importaci'|| unistr('\00f3') ||'n de Archivos',
  to_date('15/01/15','DD/MM/RR'));

   ID_OPER DSC_MOD                                            FCH_MOD 
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------
        14 Contingencia - Importación de Archivos             15-JAN-15
```

Your database and client character sets matter of course (as Justin Cave pointed out). SQL Developer picks up your language and encoding from your operating system locale by default, and you can override some things with the preferences.

You can run a query to see how it interprets chr/unistr; this is SQL Developer on OS X:

```
select chr(243), dump(chr(243)), unistr('\00f3'), dump(unistr('\00f3')) from dual;

C DUMP(CHR(243))   U DUMP(UNISTR('\00F3
- ---------------- - ------------------
  Typ=1 Len=1: 243 ó Typ=1 Len=2: 0,243
```

That won't run through SQL*Plus using many NLS_LANG settings; it's OK with AL32UTF8 (which matches my DB character set), but with US7ASCII, WE8MSWIN1252, WE8ISO8859P1 etc. or even plain UTF8, just selecting `chr(243)` will get:

```
ORA-29275: partial multibyte character
```